# Why get_posts() is not working with custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

Default taxonomies in wordpress include [Category], [Tag]... now I want to customize a taxonomy with name `post_types`:

```
function custom_post_types() {
   register_taxonomy('post_types', 'post', [
       'hierarchical'      => true,
       'labels'            => __( 'Post Types' ),
       'show_ui'           => true,
       'show_admin_column' => true,
       'query_var'         => true,
       'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'post-type' ),   
   ]);
}

add_action('init', 'custom_post_types');
```

I'm doing that and it's working!!! Then, I query posts:

```
$args = [
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'post_types',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $myTerm
            ]
        ]
];

$posts = get_posts($args);

var_dump($posts); // results is empty
```

The query result is empty although my data exists. But if query with default taxonomy of wordpress (as category or tag...) then the result is always correct.

I think my custom taxonomy has some problem but I don't know exactly what's wrong?

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: It looks good... Have you checked `$myTerm` is a valid `slug` for your `post_types` custom taxonomy?

Comment: yes, I checked $myTerm and it is a valid with slug in wp_terms table :)

Comment: In which files do you place both pieces of code?

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated your code in a dummy WP install and it works for me.

But please be careful because your `labels` value in `register_taxonomy` params isn't valid and your custom taxonomy name defaults to **Categories** which may induce to confusion with WP original post categories.

I'd advice to replace your `register_taxonomy` params with `'labels'=> ['name' => __('Post Types')],` and be sure to apply a term of this taxonomy to your post.

```
function custom_post_types() {
   register_taxonomy('post_types', 'post', [
       'hierarchical'      => true,
       'labels'            => ['name' => __('Post Types')],
       'show_ui'           => true,
       'show_admin_column' => true,
       'query_var'         => true,
       'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'post-type' ),
   ]);
}

add_action('init', 'custom_post_types');
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jordi Nebot, I tries in my project but it not working :(, I don't know why, may be I will try install WP again :)

Comment: I fixed it, my structure source code is wrong, this problem not from wordpress. thank you Jordi Nebot :)